# Giving a provided scope dependency to a spring boot fat jar running embedded tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-3

1. I have a fat jar which has a "provided" scoped maven dependency on a
   particular jar. I've ensured that this provided dependency is not
   packaged with the fat jar and is supposed to be provided at the
   runtime. Based on what I've read, if this was not embedded tomcat, I
   could provide any "provided" scoped jars by dumping them inside
   tomcat/lib folder.

Is there a way to replicate this with a fat jar
running in embedded tomcat?

Comment: Sorry but you question is not clear what your real problem is... and please add your pom file ... JDK version, spring boot version etc. and what you like to achieve..